# Notificação local ionic v1

Tags: ionic, cordova-plugin

Boa noite.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda de como utilizar o cordovaLocalNotification?

Criei um botão de teste na view com a função ng-click="testeNotificacao()"

E no meu controller está assim:

.controller('ListagemController', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
    $scope.listas = $rootScope.listas;

```
$scope.testeNotificacao = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: "1",
        message: "Teste",
        title: "Teste titulo"
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("Notificação teste");
    });
}
```

})

Porém quando eu clico no botão ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
    at Object.schedule (ng-cordova.js:5042)
    at Scope.$scope.testeNotificacao (controller.js:57)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), :4:239)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)

Eu não sei usar muito bem esse plugin, por isso queria uma ajuda.

E quando fui instalar o plugin como estava na documentação do cordova:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

Ele me deu o seguinte warning:

Installing "cordova-plugin-local-notification" for android
android-sdk version check failed ("C:\apploja\followork\platforms\android\cordova\android_sdk_version"), continuing anyways.
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 5.1.1, failed version requirement: >=6.0.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-local-notification' for android

Alguém por gentileza poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Att,
Maurício.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro erro é referente ao plugin não estar instalado. O segundo erro, da instalação (ou seja ele é o primeiro erro) é referente ao plugin local-notifications não funcionar no cordova-android 5.1.1 você precisa atualizar o seu cordova primeiro antes de instalar o plugin. Isso pode ser feito utilizando o cordova-cli na linha de comando:

```
cordova platform update android
```